# Rear outdoor range hood turns on when doorbell rings

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I have an outdoor range that is on my back porch that is built into the wall.  There is a GFCI outlet right next to the range (not sure if that is related).  For some reason when someone rings the doorbell of my house the range hoods' fan turns on.  Does that make any sense to anybody?  Some kind of power surge?  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Wow .....either gremlins or someone screwed up some wiring.

Comment: Does the fan turn off when the doorbell stops ringing?

Comment: Is the doorbell a traditionally wired system, or is it wireless?  Or have wireless componets such as extend-a-chime?  Does the range hood have a remote control? Or does it have remote control capability?

Comment: No the fan does not turn off when the doorbell stops ringing.  It works as if someone hit the normal button to turn on the fan when someone hits the doorbell.  The only thing I have noticed is there is a digital display on the fan that is supposed to state the speed of the fan (1-5), however it displays the number then flashes "F" - I suppose for fault but I need to find the manual still.

Comment: Doorbell is traditionally wired, not wireless.  Hood does not have a remote control (at least that I know of).  It is a Zephyr (http://zephyronline.com) but I'm not sure which model - it just came with the house.

Comment: Actually I just managed to find the model  It's this one http://zephyronline.com/products/essentials_power/tempest_i_pro_style

Comment: I see a [wireless remote control](http://zephyronline.com/products/essentials_power/tempest_i_pro_style) as an option (click features).  I would further investigate how the doorbell system works.  I suspect prior owner may have had extend-a-chimes or like wireless add-on and they didn't take the transmitter but unplugged and took the receivers.  I suspect two wireless systems are interfering with each other.

Comment: @Tyson - I'm with you on this one. I took the time to pull up the manual and found that a flashing "F" mean to clean the filter on page 17. Then on page 18 there is a bold note saying the RF Remove Control is an optional acces. Meaning it does receive RF commands. Try their tech line 888-880-836 you can always look like a damn good service person by calling the manufacturer's techs. and letting them walk you through it.